# Adding data to an eloquent collection?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Im getting various data out of my database.

```
Product::with('users');
```

I also have toe execute a complex raw query to get back some information. This is returned as an array.

In my method I would like to get products with users and then add on the data from my raw query to this collection, but this data comes back as an array. Something like:

```
Product::with('users');
Product->extraData = $rawQuery;
```

How can I add the raw query output to my Product Collection?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-put ?

Answer (score 0):

By using Eloquent Facade like Product:: you will get an Eloquent Model object as a result or an Eloquent Collection object as a result, including results retrieved via the get method or accessed via a relationship.

Now, if i understand correctly, you need to add a single extraData property to Eloquent Collection model alongside with Collection items? Or you need to add extraData for each Product ?

- If you need to add additional property to Eloquent Collection object, maybe it is a good idea to use a Custom Collection. Please read this section: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections#custom-collections .

  ```
  <?php namespace App;

  use App\CollectionWithExtraData;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class User extends Model 
  {

      public function newCollection(array $models = [])
      {
          return new CollectionWithExtraData($models);
      }
  }
  ```

  And maybe your CollectionWithExtraData can have let's say a

  ```
  public function setExtraData() {

  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  public $extraData = array();
  ```
- If you need extraData for each Product Eloquent Model, just create a new attribute within your Eloquent Model, make it public and set your extra data when needed. Make use of setExtraData() method and $extraData property from above